# Android studio: variable intent might not have been initialized

Tags: android

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                       int position, long row_id){
                Final Intent intent;

                switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page1.class);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page2.class);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page3.class);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page4.class);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page5.class);
                        break;

                }
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
```

### Here is my android studio code for a spinner to open another activity.
Although I declare the intent in the switch, the studio is still warning me that variable intent might not have been initialized. How can I solve it ? Thank You.

After changing to Intent intent = new Intent();
my apps will suddenly shut down
any reason will coursing that error?

Comment: Add a default case and initialize the intent there. Or just assign it null at the declaration.

Comment: You can just declare the intent like final Intent intent = new Intent();

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways:

1-  `Intent intent = new Intent();` initialize the field then change it

2- use `default` in your switch case and set a value for initent in there as well in cases when none of the above cases were valid :

```
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page1.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page2.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page3.class);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page4.class);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page5.class);
                    break;
                default: intent =new Intent(...)
                         // position is non of above cases give intent a 
                         //value
            }
```

**EDITED**
I have edited the code for you :

```
            switch (position) {
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page2.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page3.class);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page4.class);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page5.class);
                    break;
                default:intent = new Intent(Eng_page1.this, Eng_page1.class);

            }
```

Comment: The second way one will still produce that warning.

Comment: I just checked it in IDEA it's ok I edited my answer as well for you for more detail

Comment: Yes now you initialized it. Its only ok now. But not even really ok as why starting an empty intent? You should return there.

Comment: What should I type in the () to stay in the first page until user select option from spinner?

Comment: my idea is user stay on the Eng_page1 activity and open another activity until they pick the option from the spinner

Comment: remove case 1 and replace it in default I will edit the code as well for you